# Class<? extends RetryActionResultDto> is undefined for the type CLASS

Tags: java

```
private Service generateActionResponse(@Nonnull Class<? extends RetryActionResultDto> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            ...
        } else if (response.getRetryDecision() {
          ....
        }
    }

public interface RetryActionResultDto extends DTO {

    public RetryDecision getRetryDecision();

    public boolean isSuccess();

}
```

but I get exception

> The method isSuccess() is undefined for the type Class

what i can do?

Comment: your response is an instance of Class not RetryActionResultDto

Comment: hmm so what can i do? In this method I want to use all classes that implements RetryActionResultDto interface

Comment: Harsha R's answer is correct, his will take any instance of a class that implements RetryActionResultDto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write the method definition as this:

```
private <T extends RetryActionResultDto> String generateActionResponse(
            T response) {
..
}
```

which says that the method parameter accepts instances of `RetryActionResultDto` or its subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is a class .. not an instance of that class. Hence the error.

Try changing it to:

```
private Service generateActionResponse(@Nonnull RetryActionResultDto response) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        ...
    } else if (response.getRetryDecision() {
      ....
    }
}
```

An instance of a subclass would also pass through it.

Comment: should be generic, all classes that implements RetryActionResultDto can be used.

Comment: @senzacionale : all classes implementing RetryActionResultDto can be used following harsha's code..

Answer (score 1):

```
private <T> Service generateActionResponse(@Nonnull T extends RetryActionResultDto response) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        ...
    } else if (response.getRetryDecision() {
        ....
    }
}
```

But, since `RetryActionResultDto` is an interfce, the method only accepts arguments which are subtypes of `RetryActionResultDto`, even without generics.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is wrong. `Class<? extends RetryActionResultDto>` is a `Class` and not an object of a class implementing `RetryActionResultDto`.

if you want objects whose class has implemented `RetryActionResultDto` to be passed as arguments then you can use

```
private Service generateActionResponse(@Nonnull RetryActionResultDto response) {
```

as the passed argument has implemented the interface it will have all the methods declared in the interface and the actual implementation of the methods will be called in the runtime with respect to the passed object.